# Silverlight Resize Image and Final File Size

Tags: c#, silverlight, image

I build a file uploader using silverlight and http://imagetools.codeplex.com/.

Its all ok, but my final file is about 300KB(size) with an 400 x 300(resolution).

When i open it on MS Paint and Save It as jpg again the size is set to normal.

my suspect is de enconde o file is a (png) but i don't now how.

My Code:

```
        public static byte[] resize(string extension,int width,int height,int orientation)
    {
        //Decoders.AddDecoder<BmpDecoder>();
        //Decoders.AddDecoder<PngDecoder>();
        Decoders.AddDecoder<JpegDecoder>();
        //Decoders.AddDecoder<GifDecoder>();

        var newImg = new ExtendedImage();
        if (orientation == 0)
            newImg = ExtendedImage.Resize(img, width, height, new ImageTools.Filtering.NearestNeighborResizer());
        else  
            newImg = ExtendedImage.Resize(img, height, width, new ImageTools.Filtering.NearestNeighborResizer());


        //newImg = applyWaterMark(newImg);
        //var s = new MemoryStream();
        var s = newImg.ToStreamByExtension(extension);
        return ReadFully(s); 
    }
```

Comment: The default quality ImageTools uses for jpeg encoding is 100%. If you save the file from a paint program at that quality, is there still a big difference? What is the "normal" size? Also, I think your AddDecoder calls should be in a static constructor so they're only added once, not called every time you call your method.

Comment: solved!!            var e = new ImageTools.IO.Jpeg.JpegEncoder();
            var s = new MemoryStream();
            e.Quality = 90;
            
            e.Encode(newImg,s);

            //var s = newImg.ToStream();
            return s.GetBuffer();

Comment: Please place your solution as an answer to this quesion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved!!

```
var e = new ImageTools.IO.Jpeg.JpegEncoder();
var s = new MemoryStream(); e.Quality = 90;
e.Encode(newImg,s);
 //var s = newImg.ToStream();
 return s.GetBuffer();
```